# Sentrifugo HRS system Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_runtime() in

Tags: php, web, xampp

I am creating an account in the Sentrifugo HRS system and when I am adding the mail server I get the php error I tried to modify it but nothing. [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_runtime() in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZETQp.png)

I tried to change line with this **2408 **

```
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_runtime')) {
        $magic_quotes = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
```

but it didn't work either.
[Another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w2Ji.png)

Comment: Sentrifugo hasn't been updated since 2017 and requires a minimum of PHP 5.3, which indicates that this package is extremely out of date and won't work on any modern PHP system.

Comment: So this system is war of use until it is adapted to the latest versions of phpmailservice.

Comment: The last update to it was so long ago that I would assume it has been abandoned. You may need to search for an alternative solution to meet your requirements. Or I guess you could attempt to modify the code yourself.